# Why aren't these sentences correct?

Tags: present-tense, perfect-aspect

​Hello everyone! I have a very easy question. Why aren't these sentences correct?

-I haven't received an answer (on my mobile phone) for more than a week.

-This offence is called XxXxXx and occurs when you comment on a thread that hasn't received an answer for more than a week.

I'm using Present Perfect with the duration form: "for a week" but I found out they're not correct and I personally can't understand why.

Comment: Who told you they're incorrect?

Comment: If you search "hasn't received an answer for" on Google you can see only three results.

Comment: Many correct locutions produce few results from the google.  But aside from that, your search is too narrow.  Did you try "haven't received an answer in" for instance?

Comment: Using _haven't_ instead of _hasn't_ returns tens of thousands or results. @deadrat's question still stands, who told you they're incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that these sentences are not correct is wrong. Both of these sentences are perfectly fine.

Just because you can't find very many people who have used exactly the same  construction on Google, it doesn't mean that it was ungrammatical. If you Google "hasn't been to school for", which is a grammatically equivalent construction, you get lots of hits.